# makefile: toggle value of variable based on boolean env var

Tags: if-statement, makefile, boolean

I have an env var INTEGRATION that is set to true or false.

I would like to set the values of variables based on whether INTEGRATION is set to true or false.

I have tried:

```
ifeq ($(INTEGRATION),false)
  PRODUCTION_URL="production" 
else
  PRODUCTION_URL="integration"
endif
```

and also

```
if [ ${SNOOTY_INTEGRATION} == false ]; then \
    echo "HIT THE TRUTH"; \
    PRODUCTION_URL="https://docs.mongodb.com"; \
fi
```

after running

```
export INTEGRATION=true
make help
```

in terminal, I run `make help`:

```
help:
    echo "prod url ${PRODUCTION_URL}";
```

in the first case, it print `prod url integration` and in the second case, it prints `prod url`  -- when the desired behavior is for it to print, `prod url production`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `env INTEGRATION=true` is wrong.

That doesn't set the environment variable in the current shell: it only sets that environment variable in the `env` command.

You can either use:

```
$ export INTEGRATION=true
$ make help
```

(set the variable in the shell, so all subsequent commands can see it until you un-export it again), or you can use:

```
$ env INTEGRATION=true make help
```

Which is essentially the same thing as (the more common and shorter):

```
$ INTEGRATION=true make help
```

(set the variable only for this invocation of `make`).

But you can't use:

```
$ env INTEGRATION=true
$ make help
```

**ETA**

If that doesn't work there must be something else about your environment you haven't explained.  Please provide a complete self-contained example that shows the problem.  For example, I don't know what the shell if-statement you show in your question is for or how it relates to the rest of your question.  This works for me:

```
$ cat Makefile
ifeq ($(INTEGRATION),false)
  PRODUCTION_URL="production"
else
  PRODUCTION_URL="integration"
endif

help:
        echo "prod url ${PRODUCTION_URL}";

$ make help
echo "prod url "integration"";
prod url integration

$ export INTEGRATION=true
$ make help
echo "prod url "integration"";
prod url integration

$ export INTEGRATION=false
$ make help
echo "prod url "production"";
prod url production
```

Comment: Thank you for that important note! I am still not getting desired behavior - setting `export INTEGRATION=false` and then running `make help` results in `echo "prod url  <empty-space>;`

Comment: Are you sure you haven't mistyped the name of a variable?  There's no way that value can be empty because the if-statement WILL set it to one value or the other.  So all I can suggest is that you mistyped a variable name.

Comment: Also note, you really don't want to include quotes in the makefile variable assignment.  Quotes are not special to make so the value of these variables actually contains the quotes as well which is probably not what you want.